# Why different behaviors for list concatenation?

Tags: scala

What is the difference between `a ::: b` and `a.:::(b)` ?

```
scala> val a = List(1,2,3,4)
a: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> val b = List(5)
b: List[Int] = List(5)

scala> a.:::(b)
res6: List[Int] = List(5, 1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> a ::: b
res7: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All functions in Scala which end with a `:` are right-associative and, thus, the expression `a ::: b` evaluates to `b.:::(a)`.

Answer (score 3):

When you use [*infix notation*](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#arity-1), methods (or operators) that end with `:` are right associative - in other words, the method is called on the object to its right, and the object to its left is passed as an argument.

So `1 :: Nil` is the same as `Nil.::(1)`. Just as `a ::: b` is the same as `b.:::(a)`.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you type

```
a ::: b
```

the last ':' makes the function right associative. 
Thus, you are calling `:::` on `b` not `a`:

```
b.:::(a)
```